# Problem to remove a backup - ANDROID STUDIO

Tags: java, android, mobile

Intent intent1 = new Intent(Questions.this, Questions.class);
                    startActivity(intent1);

Little problem in my learning.
Sorry for my frenchglish ^^

A variable changes every time, i press a button, it backs up and assigns it ++.

In the button input if the variable == in table REPONSE.Length, It restarts the activity and it REMOVE the backup.

My problem is that the backup does not remove itself while the activity restarts well.

Every time i support the activity it raises again without being able to start again at stage 0.

```js
    int REPONSE[]= new int[5]; //tableau des reponses
    int Question = 0;
     
     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.questions);
     
     
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            Question = sharedPreferences.getInt("num", 0);
     
     
     cardView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
     
       //Restart si Question == REPONSE.length
     if (Question == REPONSE.length){
                        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                        editor.remove("num");
                        editor.apply();
                        
                        Intent intent1 = new Intent(Questions.this, Questions.class);
                        startActivity(intent1);
     
                    }
     
                 //Sauvegarde de la variable
                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putInt("num", Question++);
                    editor.apply();
     
                  //Incrementation +1
                    Question++;
       }
            }); }
```

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 points that I wold recommend you:

**Point 1:**

Try giving your Shared preference a name. Example:

`sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefName", MODE_PRIVATE);`

If you are not giving a name to the shared preference android can fall into ambiguity and create a new Sharedpreference thus not affecting the old one.

Even you are creating a new SharedPreference inside the onClick method(this process is wrong), and there the android system is not being able to understand which Shared Preference to use thus not affecting the sharedpreference data that you want to change.

**Point 2:**

This not so important as the first one but to change the data of an already existing preference you need not to delete the preference instead just change the value, and it will be updated to your requirement:

`sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("num", Question++).apply();`

**Point 3:**

- Create SharedPreference object once inside the class where it can
  have global scope.
- Initialize the SharedPreference only once in an activity inside
  onCreate method.

Make your code something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
        ConstraintLayout layout;
        int Question = 0;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);
            layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);

            sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefName", MODE_PRIVATE);
            Question = sharedPreferences.getInt("num",0);
            layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("num", Question++).apply();
                }
            });

        }
}
```

Comment: @AudricPazza try the codes first in your projects and then accept and vote the answer that helped you solving the question.In StackOverflow this is the best way to say thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#remove(java.lang.String)) remove() removes a value once commit() is called.  So you have to change editor.apply() to editor.commit()

```
//Restart si Question == REPONSE.length
     if (Question == REPONSE.length){
                        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                        editor.remove("num");
                        editor.commit();  //editor.apply() won't work
```